# Socket hang up in Nestjs for uploading files with minio client

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, minio

I am uploading files to my **minio** storage using [nestjs-minio-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-minio-client).

I have my application running on a docker container behind Nginx as a reverse proxy.

The minio storage is on another docker container on another server.

The uploading process **works fine** and the file is uploaded to the storage correctly. But the problem is that **after a while**, no more files can be uploaded **unless** I restart the container.

This is due to **socket hang up**:

```
   [Nest] 20   - 11/29/2020, 12:36:57 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] socket hang up +899287ms
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:459:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Here comes my implementation:

I have imported the minioModule in my module:

```
import { MinioModule } from 'nestjs-minio-client';

@Module({
         imports: [ MinioModule.register({
                                    endPoint: minioConstants.MINIO_ENDPOINT,
                                    useSSL: true,
                                    accessKey: minioConstants.MINIO_ACCESSKEY,
                                    secretKey: minioConstants.MINIO_SECRETKEY,})],
          
         controllers: [...],
         providers: [...],
         exports: [...]
```

This is how I pass the file in my controller (using multer):

```
    @Put('/avatar')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('avatar'))
    async uploadAvatar(
        @UploadedFile() avatarFile: IMulterFile
    ){
        return {data: await this.uploadService.uploadImage(avatarFile)}
    }
```

And here comes the uploadService:

```
import { Injectable, Logger, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MinioService } from 'nestjs-minio-client';
import * as crypto from 'crypto'
import { IMulterFile } from '@shared/interfaces/file.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
    private readonly baseBucket = 'users' //fix ==> read from env

    public get client() {
      return this.minio.client;
    }

    constructor(private readonly minio: MinioService) {}

    public async uploadImage(file: IMulterFile, baseBucket: string = this.baseBucket) {
      if(!(file.mimetype.includes('image/jpeg') || file.mimetype.includes('image/png'))) {
        throw new HttpException('Error uploading file', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
      }
      let temp_filename = Date.now().toString()
      let hashedFileName = crypto.createHash('md5').update(temp_filename).digest("hex");
      let ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'), file.originalname.length);
      const metaData = {
        'Content-Type': file.mimetype,
        'X-Amz-Meta-Testing': 1234,
      };
      let filename = hashedFileName + ext
      const fileName: string = `${filename}`;
      const fileBuffer = file.buffer;
      await this.client.putObject(baseBucket,fileName,fileBuffer,metaData)

    return {filename}
  }

  async delete(objetName: string, baseBucket: string = this.baseBucket) {
    await this.client.removeObject(baseBucket, objetName);
  }
}
```

I have also tried [nestjs-minio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-minio) as the client, but the same issue occurs after a while that the container is used.

Are there any ideas about why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is weird but the problem was with the minio server itself!
I tried the code with minio playground and it worked fine!
So we set up the latest version of minio instance again and everything is fine now!